# Spring Security for REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, curl, spring-security

I enabled Spring Security for my REST application but not getting authorized when using curl.

**Security.xml**

```
<sec:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <sec:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler" />

    <sec:logout />
</sec:http>

<beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="net.himalay.security.MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:user-service>
            <sec:user name="temporary" password="temporary" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <sec:user name="user" password="userPass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

**CustomEntryPoint**

```
@Component
public final class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        LOG.info("---------RestAuthenticationEntryPoint----------");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("rest")
public class MultitenantController {

    @Autowired
    private MultitenantService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUserInfo(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return service.getUser(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> getCustomers() {
        return service.getUsers();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/todo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<TodoItem> getTransactions(@PathVariable Long id) {
        HttpHeaders headers = addAccessControllAllowOrigin();
        return getUserInfo(id).getTodoItems();
    }
}
```

**$curl -i -X -u user:userPass `http://localhost:8080/mt-rest/rest/user/1/todo`**

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: user
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ADA11C09484E658C38D8385CABA0CFAE; Path=/mt-rest/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 975
Date: Fri, 31 Jan 2014 17:14:45 GMT
```

After taking out security pattern from security.xml, it works fine. What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: use auto-config=false on http. And empty <sec:form-login />. Also, how are you passing the userid and password? Is it something like a post method?(curl?)

Comment: can you try  curl --data "name=user&password=userPass" and try?

Answer (score 0):

You have only defined a form-login module. I believe that you also need to specify http-basic. For example:

```
<sec:http-basic />
```

Comment: Jsight: I added <sec:http-basic /> in the line before <sec:form-login.., same result.

Comment: It works if I remove the custom entry point "restAuthenticationEntryPoint", not sure why