# Trouble authenticating to Spring Boot Web App via Rest Assured

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, rest-assured

I'm trying to write tests for our API endpoints. In order to be authorized to use them, the user needs to first authenticate. I'm able to hit protected endpoints and parse the 401 unauthorized response, but I can't seem to figure out how to authenticate at all.

Current attempt at rest assured test code:

```
@Test
public void loginTest2() throws IOException
{
    SessionFilter session = new SessionFilter();

    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://localhost:8080";

    Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .config( RestAssured.config().sessionConfig( new SessionConfig().sessionIdName( "SESSION" ) ) )
            .filter( session )
            .auth().form( "dev", "test", FormAuthConfig.springSecurity() )
        .when()
            .post( "/login" )
        .then()
            .statusCode( 401 ).extract().response();

    System.out.println( "response :" + response.asString() );
    System.out.println( "response.cookie( \"SESSION\" )  :" + response.cookie( "SESSION" ) );
    System.out.println( "sessionFilter.getSessionId() :" + session.getSessionId() );
}
```

Output from test:

```
response :{"timestamp":1534278154501,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized.","path":"/login"}
response.cookie( "SESSION" )  :null
sessionFilter.getSessionId() :null
```

Current Spring Security config:

```
@Override
public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{
    http.addFilterBefore(
            new CustomLoginPageFilter(), DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.class );

    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler( accessDeniedHandler() )
            .authenticationEntryPoint( new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint() )
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/login" ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage( "/login" )
            .failureHandler( customAuthFailureHandler )
            .successHandler( customAuthSuccessHandler )
            .permitAll() );
}
```

CustomLoginPageFilter:

```
public class CustomLoginPageFilter extends GenericFilterBean
{
    @Override
    public void doFilter( ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        if ( ( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null )
            && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()
            && "/login".equals( ( (HttpServletRequest) request ).getRequestURI() ) )
        {
            ( (HttpServletResponse) response ).sendRedirect( "/" );
        }
        chain.doFilter( request, response );
        }
}
```

login.html form:

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="/login" id="login-form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control underlined" name="username" id="login-username" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control underlined" name="password" id="login-password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your password"/>
     </div>  

    <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="login-submit">
             <em class="fa fa-key" id="login-submitButtonIcon"></em> Login</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

I can provide additional details, but I'm not entirely sure which snippets will be relevant.

Comment: can you include the code in CustomLoginPageFilter, what does it do

Comment: I've updated the post to include that class - it's used to redirect non-anonymous users away from the /login page. Also added our login form HTML.

Comment: So, the customLoginpageFilter doesn't do anything except redirecting to root upon successful authentication. You should be doing this in customAuthSuccessHandler.

Comment: If you don't have any authentication logic in RestAuthenticationEntryPoint, remove it. ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488724/spring-security-for-rest

Comment: can you update login.html to include the form submit action

Comment: Updated to include submit action